# How can I remove brackets next to the link in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

`Some sentance startx here blah blah [Example](https://someSite.com/another/blah/blah)`

and I want this string to become this one:

`Some sentance startx here blah blah Example`

I have tried this regex:

`"[\[\]]\(\S*(https|http)*\.(ru|com)\S*"`

but I get this:

`Some sentance startx here blah blah [Example`

The code:

```
pattern = r"[\[\]]\(\S*(https|http)*\.(ru)\S*"
text = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
```

Comment: In general, debuggers are your most powerful tools to troubleshoot non-working code. A web search will turn up various regex debuggers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
\[([^][]*)]\(http[^\s()]*\)
```

**Replace with `\1`**.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/m4XPbP/1).

**Python code snippet**:

```py
text = re.sub(r'\[([^][]*)]\(http[^\s()]*\)', r'\1', text)
```

Comment: Ok, this is exactly what I wanted, but how can I exclude all the links for the .ru domain?

Comment: Ok, based on your solution I have made some changes that fits my goals: `string = re.sub(r'\[([^][]*)]\(\S*(https|http)*\.(ru)\S*', r'\1', string)
`

Comment: @ATOM great you could build upon the solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
string = 'Some sentance startx here blah blah [Example](https://someSite.com/another/blah/blah)'

string = string.split("]")[0].replace("[","")

print(string)
```

Comment: sorry but this is not working properly. If I have the string like this `Some sentance startx here blah blah [Example](https://someSite.com/another/blah/blah)` it will only print `Example`